# How to change Json value to fit Enum case sensitivity using Springboot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, enums

I've run into an issue while building out my controller. I am sending a GET request to a third party and receiving back data that I then map to a DTO. One of those pieces of data is Address and AddressType.

I am calling a third party with a GET request using:

```
        final ResponseEntity<AddressResponseDTO> response =
                restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(),
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        request,
                        AddressResponseDTO.class);
```

This is my Json Response:

```
"addressType": "Mailing",
"line1": "123 Ave",
"line2": "",
"city": "New York",
"state": "NY",
```

Originally, I am mapping these values using

```
    @JsonProperty("addressType")
    private AddressType addressType;

    @JsonProperty("line1")
    private String line1;

    @JsonProperty("line2")
    private String line2;

    @JsonProperty("city")
    private String city;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;
```

Address Type is an enum.

```
public enum AddressType {
        BUSINESS,
        MAILING,
        DELIVERY

}
```

The problem is that the Json response returns Business instead of BUSINESS which throws an error.

I tried adding this to the DTO:

```
   @JsonProperty("addressType")
    private String addressEnum;

    private AddressType addressType = AddressType.valueOf(addressEnum.toUpperCase());
```

But it just ignores this. Is there a simple way to map Business to BUSINESS? I feel like this should be a simple Springboot annotation but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to create a custom deserializer using Jackson. This allows you to write custom code to perform the deserialization, giving you total control over how the data is interpreted.

First, define a new deserializer class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CaseInsensitiveEnumDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<AddressType> {

    @Override
    public AddressType deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) 
        throws IOException {
        return AddressType.valueOf(jsonParser.getText().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Then, in your DTO, use the @JsonDeserialize annotation to specify this new deserializer class

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

```
public class AddressResponseDTO {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CaseInsensitiveEnumDeserializer.class)
    private AddressType addressType;
    // your fields and methods
}
```

This code will now correctly deserialize any case variation of the AddressType enum values from the JSON response.

Comment: I tried implementing this but got the same error ```cannot deserialize value of type `path.AddressType` from String \"Mailing\": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [BUSINESS, MAILING, DELIVERY] ``` Maybe I'm implementing this wrong?

Comment: I moved the JsonDeserialize annotation to the top of the AddressType enum class and its now working. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using Jackson for deserialization, which supports ignoring case on enums.

When initializing you `RestTemplate`, you can turn that feature on.

```
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
  .json()
  .featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
  .defaultMessageConverters()
  .additionalMessageConverters(jsonMessageConverter)
  .build();
```

Comment: I tried this and it just keeps giving me the same error cannot deserialize Mailing to MAILING. I feel like I've tried everything and it just keeps ignoring it

Answer (score 0):

I tried solution of Christopher Schneider but this didn't work. In analizing the problem I added the next code:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().forEach(httpMessageConverter -> System.out.println(httpMessageConverter.getClass()));
```

I got the next output:

```
class org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
```

And because there are now two MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter it didn't work for me because the defaultMessageConverter was used.

I solved the problem by getting the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter from the restTemplate and setting my ObjectMapper option:

```
...

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .uriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(baseUrl))
            .defaultMessageConverters()
            .build();

    addObjectMapperOptionsForJacksonConverter(restTemplate);

....

private static void addObjectMapperOptionsForJacksonConverter(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream()
            .filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No default class is configured by Spring of class type MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. This should be the case!"));
    jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

Another option could be to use Christopher Schneider code without the defaultMessageConverters() but I didn't test this if this causes other problems.